# Multiple equations with relations.

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm very bad at math so please correct me or let me know if I'm posting in the wrong section.

I have a set of equations (in reality any number > 2) but if its solvable for 3 it would be good enough.

Here it is :

1. $S_i  X_i - R_i+Y_i = C$ where $0\leq i \leq n$ (or 2)
2. $R_i = -S_i + \sum_{j=0}^n S_j$

The unknowns are the $R_i$ and the $S_i$. All Xs and Ys are known and C is known and constant for all equations.

Now I would need help (if its even possible?) to solve the equation so I have a formula to calculate $S_i$ for any given $i$.

Any help or if you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.
Or if the something is missing for the equation to be solvable please let me know.

BR Tomas A

EDIT: Solved it etc, but after looking closer to at the problem I've realised I'm only interested in postive solutions of $S_i$. In reality I would like to modify $C$ to make sure the system only produces non-negative solutions.  I realise there might not be one but I'd like the closest approximation, is that possible?

Comment: This is a system of linear equations. Do you know this keyword ?

Comment: I actually do, with a bit of luck I can sort it out from here.
Thanks a million for the edit and guidence !

Comment: Good! This is well documented. Come back if you're in trouble.

Comment: I am now trying to solve the system using a Java library but it complains that the Matrix is "Singular". This would lead to infinite solutions (online solver showed me that). But for some reason none of the Java-libs I've found gives me the. What is an algorithm to get the infinite solutions of a singular matrix?

Comment: You seem to have enough internet-points but if  you want more you could post your comment as an answer and Ill mark it as correct.

Comment: Your matrix does not seem singular to me... What are the values of the $X_i$ ?

Comment: Well the $X_i$ are actually odds on a betting market so they can vary from 1.01 to 1000, but the matrix is actually just singular when there is no "Overround" on the market, that is the SUM(1/$X_i$) == 1. The $S_i$ are sizes of bets to be placed to "cash-out" from the market, hence Im only looking for non-negative solutions (cant accept laybets, aka negative sizes).